# Be $f(\vec{x})$:= $||\vec{x}||^2$ $\cdot$ $\vec{x}$, Why $f(\vec{x})^{-1}$= $||\vec{x}||^{-2/3}\cdot\vec{x}$?.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Be $f(\vec{x})$:= $||\vec{x}||^2$ $\cdot$ $\vec{x}$, Why $f(\vec{x})^{-1}$= $||\vec{x}||^{-2/3}\cdot\vec{x}$?. Where || . || is the euclidean norm.

Hello, I am trying to finish understanding a demonstration, but in this one they only indicate that the inverse of this function is this result, but I do not understand how they calculate it. Any suggestion is very helpful. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what happens when you plug one into the other?